# Bootstrap Input group not the same?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, I've got the signin example running, and I can't figure out where I've gone astray. Here's a picture. The top picture is what I get in my browser when I run my code locally -- but the example on the bootstrap site looks like the second one, below, which is what I want. What am I missing?

Cheers,

Simon

[image]

Here's the code I'm using, as well:

```
<div class="container">

  <form class="form-signin" role="form">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
  </form>

</div> <!-- /container -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example login form has custom CSS embedded in the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/5Fzbw/

```
body {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.form-signin {
  max-width: 330px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.form-signin .form-signin-heading,
.form-signin .checkbox {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.form-signin .checkbox {
  font-weight: normal;
}
.form-signin .form-control {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.form-signin .form-control:focus {
  z-index: 2;
}
.form-signin input[type="email"] {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.form-signin input[type="password"] {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```